# How to get the first day of the next month in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I need to get the first day of the next Month for a datePicker in dd/mm/yyyy format.

how can i do it?

i have this code :

```js
var now = new Date();
if (now.getMonth() == 11) {
  var current = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);
} else {
  var current = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 1);
}

console.log(current)
```

but it's give this :

```
Sat Jan 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

i need it like this `01/01/2022`

any help here =)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first of next month:

```
let d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1, 1);
```

Then to format as dd/mm/yyyy:

```
d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
```

As a runnable snippet:

```js
let d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1, 1);

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
var now = new Date();
var current;
if (now.getMonth() == 11) {
  current = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);
} else {
  current = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 1);
}

console.log(current.toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: If no language is provided to *toLocaleDateString* then it will guess based on browser or system settings, so might be d/m/y, m/d/y, y-m-d, and so on.